# Can't include React UI frameworks (Grommet)

Tags: reactjs, grommet

I have problems importing UI libraries, I had problem with ant design library so I decided to try different one, now I have problem importing Grommet.

What am I doing wrong? I added dependencies according documentation and added examples included in documentation yet still not working.

I am trying to execute [this code from documentation](https://grommet.io/docs/header/examples/)

But it doesn't look the same at all

I work with codesandbox.io, [here is link for the code on it](https://codesandbox.io/s/6nxmxk7qk)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import Heading from "grommet/components/Heading";
import Box from "grommet/components/Box";
import Header from "grommet/components/Header";
import Title from "grommet/components/Title";
import Search from "grommet/components/Search";
import Menu from "grommet/components/Menu";
import Anchor from "grommet/components/Anchor";
import "grommet-css";

class HelloWorldApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header>
          <Title>Sample Title</Title>
          <Box flex={true} justify="end" direction="row" responsive={false}>
            <Search
              inline={true}
              fill={true}
              size="medium"
              placeHolder="Search"
              dropAlign={{right: "right"}}
            />
            <Menu dropAlign={{right: "right"}}>
              <Anchor href="#" className="active">
                First
              </Anchor>
              <Anchor href="#">Second</Anchor>
              <Anchor href="#">Third</Anchor>
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Header>
        <Box>
          <Heading>
            Hello, I'm a Grommet Component styled with
            <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/grommet-css">grommet-css</a>
          </Heading>
        </Box>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var element = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorldApp />, element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your code:

```
<Menu dropAlign={{right: "right"}}>
```

was missing the icon attribute, without which the **Menu component** directly renders the **Anchor**, 
the menu-items component.

**add import for the icon of your choosing, i.e: Actions ( from the example )**

```
import Actions from 'grommet/components/icons/base/Actions';
```

**add the icon attribute to the Menu component:**

```
<Menu
   icon={<Actions />}
   dropAlign={{ right: 'right' }}
>
  <Anchor href="#" className="active">First</Anchor>
  <Anchor href="#">Second</Anchor>
  <Anchor href="#">Third</Anchor>
</Menu>
```

here's a **codesandbox.io link** which fixes your issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/237xo7y48p

Comment: I am going crazy here, I copied your exact code, still not same result https://codesandbox.io/s/6nxmxk7qk